# Unable to create DLLs: Getting DLL "is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

As the title says, I can't create a simple DLL.  I'm using VS 2017 Community Edition Version 15.8.0.  Here is the .dll code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InvWin32App.h"

#include "$StdHdr.h"

void Prc1()
{
    printf("ran procedure 1\n");
}
```

Here is the code for the header, per the MS way to do things:

```
#ifdef INVWIN32APP_EXPORTS
#define INVWIN32APP_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define INVWIN32APP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

        INVWIN32APP_API  void Prc1();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Here is the driver code:  (Update:  The driver program is an .exe program.)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "InvWin32App.h"

int main()
{
    Prc1();
}
```

It can't get any simpler than this.  I get the following error message box when I try to run the code:

```
Unable to start program
program name.dll
program name.dll is not
a valid Win32 application
```

I can create .exe programs okay.  I also got the error earlier this morning when I was running VS 2017 Version 15.7.5.  Upgrading VS didn't do any good.  I also tried to compile these as .c programs, but it didn't make any difference.

I had this problem on a couple occasions creating .exe programs using VS 2015.  I don't recall what I did, but the problem disappeared.  Any help would be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: You cannot run dlls directly, normally they get dynamically loaded into an exe.

Comment: Windows is correct. You can't run a dll directly. You probably meant to set the application (you call driver code) as the startup project instead of the dll.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not running the .dll directly.  I use the driver code, which is an .exe to call the .dll.

Comment: Your error message seems to conflict with that. Which one of these projects is the startup project?

Comment: I'm exceeding stupid today.  The startup program was the .dll, not the .exe.  Thanks so much, as that took care of the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Right click the project in your solution explorer that is the project for the executable and click "Set as startup project."

Note that "is not a valid Win32 application" is not a compile error or a link error, it is the message you get when you tried to debug something that is not executable.

You can only start executables. Executables consume dlls. These should be two seperate projects with two sets of corresponding project settings.

Comment: You can debug dlls in Visual Studio, though. Open properties of your dll project `Project > Properties`, go to `Configuration Properties > Debugging` tab, set `Attach` field to `Yes`. In the `Command` field set executable to which you will attach your .dll. Press `Apply` and `Ok` buttons. Open `Build > Configuration Manager` menu. Set `Active Solution Configuration` to `Debug`. Now you can start your target executable and start debugging your .dll. When you will press `Debug > Start Debugging`, Visual Studio will attach itself to the target process and look for your dll.

Comment: @KulaGGin Do you think the OP did all of that, ran into the error he described, then came here and asked the question he asked? I don't. However, if you are asking for an edit for better clarity, let me know what you are suggesting. If your comment is just a FYI, that's cool too.

Comment: Yep, it's just a FYI for people who will get this error trying to debug a dll. I was trying to debug a dll today and started getting this error. In my case it was because I switched to Release build configuration, and I fixed it by switching back to Debug build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you are using a 32 bit dll. If you have your 64-bit Windows OS then you must have 64 bit version of this dll too. Sometimes, even you have 64-bit dll already then it could not run, so try the other version of this dll i.e. 32 bit version of this dll.
Along with this, make a small change in your `unicurse.py` file too.
PFB the code to add:

```
import ctypes
pdlib = ctypes.CDLL("pdcurses.dll")
```

though this line of code is somewhere inside some condition, but bringing on top will help you to check, if the dll has been loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

For any one joining the party at this time, I found that this error is caused when you try to run a `32bit dll using a 64bit python`.

Now I won't go into the details as to why that won't work as above responses clearly describes that, but there are 2 solutions for this.

1. Install and 32bit python and use that to communicate with the dll.
2. Interprocess communication using the msl-loadlib library [documentation](https://msl-loadlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interprocess_communication.html)

I used the second step which seemed more sustainable. The steps I am using below can be found in the documentation link above.

- First is to create a server module that communicates with the 32 bit module

```py
#server.py
from msl.loadlib import Server32


class Server(Server32):
    # the init takes mandatory host and port as arguments
    def __init__(self, host, port, **kwargs):
        # using windll since this application is being run in windows, other options such as cdll exists
        # this assumes that the dll file is in the same directory as this file
        super(Server, self).__init__('tresdlib.dll', 'windll', host, port)
    
    # define a function that is to be called with the required arguments
    def fsl_command(self, com, doc):
        #the server32 exposes the loaded dll as lib, which you can then use to call the dll functions and pass the required arguments
        return self.lib.FSL_Command(com,doc)
```

- Then we create a client module, that sends python requests to the server module

```py
#client.py
from msl.loadlib import Client64


class Client(Client64):

    def __init__(self):
        # pass the server file we just created in module32=, the host am using is localhost, leave port as none for self assigning
        super(Client, self).__init__(module32='server', host="127.0.0.1", port=None)

    # define a function that calls the an existing server function and passes the args
    def fsl_command(self, com, doc):
        return self.request32('fsl_command', com, doc)
```

We are going to run this in a terminal but you can choose to call in another application

```
>>> from client import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> c.fsl_command(arg1,arg2)
```