# Accessing a 32bit DLL file from 64bit Python - Ctypes and msl.loadlib not working?

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I am trying to access a 32bit DLL file using 64bit Python it is not working?

I tried Ctypes and msl.loadlib modules and they have not helped me?

```
I get the error not a valid 32bit application ? When i try Cpp64() i get 
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

This is the VBA Code that i have in excel

```
Private Declare Function UTLConnectSession Lib "ATMAPI32.DLL" (ByVal hWnd&, ByVal Session$) As Long
```

It works well. When try to access the same in python it does not

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import os
import sys

myDll = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\EHLLAPI\atmapi32.dll")
print(myDll)

from msl.loadlib import LoadLibrary, IS_PYTHON_64BIT
from msl.examples.loadlib import EXAMPLES_DIR
from msl.examples.loadlib import Cpp64

cdir=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\EHLLAPI\atmapi32.dll"
Cpp64()
```

How do i get this to work in python?

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: You cannot load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process (and vice versa). Either 1) use a 32-bit python interpreter (with your 32-bit DLL), or 2) find a 64-bit version of the  DLL you want to use with your 64-bit interpreter.

Comment: I have added an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850365/6900687)